# inconsistency between format and probe-scsi-all outputs

Tags: solaris, disk, zfs

my platform:
SPARC T4-1
Generic_150400-24 sun4v sparc sun4v

1 of the disk is seems different in the output of format when I am on console cli
even though relevant disk seems same as others in the output of probe-scsi-all output
what can be wrong with c0t5000CCA07058B9F0d0 below (first disk in output)?

I did see that in front panel disk led is green as others.

strange thing is that when I was doing solaris 10 installation from CDROM installation menu for ZFS 
also could not recognize the capacity of that disk, it shows 0 MB 
(I added below example from other box so disk name in installation menu is different)

```
# format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t5000CCA07058B9F0d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A720-558.91GB>
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca07058b9f0
       1. c0t5000CCA070584ED8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070584ed8
       2. c0t5000CCA070590CD8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070590cd8
       3. c0t5000CCA070590E10d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070590e10
       4. c0t5000CCA0705836F8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705836f8
       5. c0t5000CCA0705893ECd0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705893ec
       6. c0t5000CCA0705955F0d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705955f0
       7. c0t5000CCA07059468Cd0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca07059468c
Specify disk (enter its number): ^C

{0} ok probe-scsi-all
/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@f/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@2/hub@3/storage@2
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device    AMI     Virtual CDROM   1.00

/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

FCode Version 1.00.64, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.05.00.00

Target 9
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca07059468c  SASAddress 5000cca07059468d  PhyNum 0
Target a
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device   TEAC     DV-W28S-B        AT11
  SATA device  PhyNum 6
Target b
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705836f8  SASAddress 5000cca0705836f9  PhyNum 1
Target c
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070584ed8  SASAddress 5000cca070584ed9  PhyNum 2
Target d
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070590cd8  SASAddress 5000cca070590cd9  PhyNum 3

/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

FCode Version 1.00.64, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.05.00.00

Target 9
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca07058b9f0  SASAddress 5000cca07058b9f1  PhyNum 0
Target a
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705893ec  SASAddress 5000cca0705893ed  PhyNum 1
Target b
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070590e10  SASAddress 5000cca070590e11  PhyNum 2
Target c
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705955f0  SASAddress 5000cca0705955f1  PhyNum 3

{0} ok

─ Select Disks ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  On this screen you must select the disks for installing Solaris software.
  Start by looking at the Suggested Minimum field; this value is the
  approximate space needed to install the software you've selected. For ZFS,
  multiple disks will be configured as mirrors, so the disk you choose, or the
  slice within the disk must exceed the Suggested Minimum value.
  NOTE: ** denotes current boot disk

  Disk Device                                              Available Space
  =============================================================================
  [X]    c0t5000CCA07057269Cd0                            572308 MB
) [X]    c0t5000CCA070583C94d0                            572308 MB
) [X]    c0t5000CCA0705862A4d0                            572308 MB
) [-]    c0t5000CCA070588C7Cd0                                0 MB
  [X]    c0t5000CCA07058D0A0d0                            572308 MB  (F4 to edit
) [ ]    c0t5000CCA07058F494d0                            572308 MB
  [ ]    c0t5000CCA070590FD0d0                            572308 MB
  [ ]    c0t5000CCA0705940C0d0                            572308 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems disk 0 in your `format` output has an EFI label.

See [Creating and Examining a Disk Label](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1459/disksprep-34.html#scrolltoc).

Look at the output from `prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0t5000C...` on different disks to see the difference.

Comment: this is the bad one `bash-3.2# prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0t5000CCA0705846C0d0s2
* /dev/rdsk/c0t5000CCA0705846C0d0s2 partition map
*
* Dimensions:
*     512 bytes/sector
*     668 sectors/track
*      27 tracks/cylinder
*   18036 sectors/cylinder
*   64988 cylinders
*   64986 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
       0      2    00          0 1172087496 1172087495
       2      5    00          0 1172087496 1172087495`

Comment: I changed the "bad" disk's label via format command and did an init 6
format> label
[0] SMI Label
[1] EFI Label
Specify Label type[1]: 0
Auto configuration via format.dat[no]? yes
format> quit
after init 6,
format output of 6th disk ("bad" one) below became "SUN600G cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668"
but I was expecting to have it same as others.
I dont know anymore if it is fixed already or not.
I believe not because as I pasted earlier according to probe-scsi-all all disks are same model actually.

Comment: @HalitSakca It's a label.  It might be slightly different with no change in external model depending on how the original labels were written to the disk.  It's not "bad".  Is the disk working?  The geometry is exactly the same.